# Php function within SQL statement syntax

Tags: php, sql

I have the following code. I would like username to take the value of the getUserName function however I am fighting with syntax. Can anybody tell me what should be the correct one?

```
$query = "SELECT user FROM users_entity WHERE username = getUserName()";
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use concatenation with the period:

```
$query = "SELECT user FROM users_entity WHERE username = '".mysql_real_escape_string(getUserName())."'";
```

Make sure to escape your data!

Answer (score 2):

You can't embed the result of a function directly into a string. However you can store the contents of a variable:

```
$username = mysql_real_escape_string(getUserName());
$query = "SELECT user FROM users_entity WHERE username = '$username'";
```

Or, you could concatenate your string like this:

```
$query = 'SELECT user FROM users_entity WHERE username = \'' . mysql_real_escape_string(getUserName()) . '\'';
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot interpolate (internally string-replace) PHP function names into strings.

You probably want something more like this:

```
$query = sprintf("SELECT user FROM users_entity WHERE username = '%s'"
    mysql_real_escape_string(getUserName())
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = "SELECT user FROM users_entity WHERE username = '".getUserName()."'";
```